Computing $ \nabla_X \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ for the Euclidean connection
Let $\nabla$ be the Euclidean connection on a manifold $M = \mathbb{R}^n$. If $X, Y$ is are smooth vector fields on $M$ with $Y$ given by:
$$
Y = \sum_{i}^{n} Y^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
$$
Then by this verified answer, the Euclidean connection is defined as:
$$
\nabla_X Y = \sum_{i}^{n} X(Y^i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
$$
Now, this  can be shown to equal $DY(p) \cdot X(p)$ (right?).
Here is my confusion: by linearity and the Leibniz rule, the above expression $\nabla_X Y = \sum_i \nabla_X (Y^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i})= \sum_{i} X(Y^i) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} + Y^i \nabla_X \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$
. Now, I'm not sure how to compute $\nabla_X \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$. On one hand, it seems that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is just the constant vector field pointing in the $i^{th}$ direction, so that $D \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \equiv 0$ and this new term vanishes.
But I think this is incorrect reasoning: if $D\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \equiv 0$, this would imply $\nabla_X \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} = 0$ for any vector field $X$. However, I believe that $\nabla_{e_j} e_i = \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} = \delta_{ij}$, which is not always zero.
Therefore, how do I show that, on Euclidean space and for the Euclidean connection, $ \nabla_X \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} = 0$? And how do I reconcile this with the fact that $\nabla_{e_j} e_i = \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} = \delta_{ij}$ (unless this is wrong?)

Nope. Why do you think it's $1$ when $i=j$? The vector field is globally constant.

@TedShifrin my professor said this. I didn't get it either. Thanks!

In Euclidean space,   $\nabla_{e_j} e_i = 0$  under the   rectangular coordinate system.
